# tslint - Got different result between using global and inline npm script

Tags: typescript, npm, tslint, npm-scripts

I found tslint is work correctly when I use command:

```
tslint -c tslint.json --project tsconfig.json 'src/**/*.ts'
```

But when I moved it to npm script, I found it seem don't read `tslint.json`.

My package.json like:

```
{
  "name": "short-night",
  "scripts": {
    "tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json --project tsconfig.json 'src/**/*.ts'"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-lint": "^4.5.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.11.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

[There](https://github.com/FoXZilla/short-night/blob/stackoverflow-lint/package.json#L8) is my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for the tslint is correct actually.

The globally tslint doesn't emit error because it can't find the extends. The locally tslint emit error because of "ter-indent" rather than "indent".

It's interesting that tslint has both of "indent" and "ter-indent".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'`s from the command and it should work. Generally you don't need to manually pass file paths to the `tslint` command if you also pass a `--project`, as it'll pick up paths from the project.

```
"tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json --project tsconfig.json src/**/*.ts",
```

Comment: It still works incorrectly when I remove path or `'`.